# Does it make any sense to submit an unfinished iOS app to Apple Store to get some initial feedback from Apple?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm developing an iOS app and I'm not sure if some of the things I've done will be approved by Apple. Sometimes the reasons of rejections are very hard to predict and I'd like to know if something is wrong earlier.

Does it make sense to submit an unfinished app to Apple Store with a release date couple months in the future just to get some valuable feedback from Apple? I'm pretty sure they'll reject such an app, because they don't allow beta versions to be submitted to Apple Store. But, will they provide me some valuable feedback, that certain parts of the app or of the implementation need to be changed for the app to be approved when it's finished? Or, will they just reject it because it's not finished and won't provide any feedback about the already implemented parts?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Why do you think it will be rejected when it's finished?

Comment: It'll be rejected for not providing enough functionality, being too buggy, etc. They don't have time to write detailed and/or valuable feedback for every one of the thousands of app updates they review every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tricky. In my experience, if they reject it, they'll reject it for the first problem they find. They won't give you a list of reasons. They won't review it thoroughly once they've seen a reason to say no.

So, while I can't see any harm in doing it, there's no guarantee you'll be rejected in a way that gives useful feedback. More likely they'll pick you up on a simple point, and you'll be no wiser.

*Updated*

Plus, bear in mind, the review system isn't wholly consistent. I've had apps accepted by one reviewer, only to be rejected next time because the later reviewer is more thorough. You could have your alpha app accepted, only to see the polished version rejected after months of work.

A better approach might be to discuss the specific rule you *might* be breaking on the Apple Dev Forum.

Answer (score 1):

Prior approval of an app, or a type of app, creates no precedent for future app approvals.  Developers have submitted bug fix updates and had that app update rejected for violating some App store rule or guideline completely unrelated to the changes.

However an app rejection will give you valuable feedback.  So if you think your app is on the edge of acceptability, a rejection might provide useful information regarding the risk of continued development.

For any submission, you need to make sure the app won't be rejected outright for bugs or crashes or other reasons unrelated to the feedback you are seeking.

And if you are a featured high profile or famous developer, then Apple might contact you regarding feedback on your apps under development.

Answer (score 0):

it's almost never checked for critical bugs, it's checked for using private APIs, breaking license agreements and so on.